# Setting the length of the X-Axis of a Highchart to be 24 hours from time of first data point with less than 24 hours of data to display

Tags: highcharts

I am building a chart which will show weather data for the current day, import the data from a JSON file. I would like the X-axis to always be 24 hours in length from the first data point (typically a few minutes past midnight of the current day.

I have figured out how to extract the time of the first data point and how to calculate the value required for 24 hours later.

My problem is how do I assign these values to the variables I am using to set the max x-axis value when the chart loads?

My code is to determine the min and max X-axis values and plot the chart is

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/xrange.js"></script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA" onload"populatexAxis_data()">

  <h1 align="center" style="font-family:verdana; color:#151B54">PYWWS Highcharts Test Web Page</h1>
  <h2 align="center" style="font-family:verdana; color:#151B54">Last 24 Hours Weather Data</h2>
  <div id="Highcharts">

    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
      <!--Outside Temperature and Humidity-->
      <div id="chart1_container" style="width: 1250px; height: 600px; border:1px solid black; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </figure>

    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
      <!--Rain-->
      <div id="chart2_container" style="width: 1250px; height: 400px; border:1px solid black; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </figure>

    var minXaxisValue;
    var maxXaxisValue;

    var chart1;
    var chart2;

    var LeftMarginSize = 100;
    var RightMarginSize = 150;

    function populatexAxis_data() {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'data/today_highchart.json',
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data) {
              temp_data = data;
              console.log(data);
              minValue = data[0][0];
              maxValue = minValue + (24 * 3600 * 1000);
            },
          });
        }

        //Import data from the JSON file
        function getChartdata() {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'data/today_highchart.json',
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data) {
              temp_data = data;
              //Outside Temperature and Humidity
              chart1.series[0].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[1]])); //Outside Temperature
              chart1.series[1].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[2]])); //Outside Humidity
              chart1.series[2].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[4]])); //Dew Point  
              chart1.series[3].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[3]])); //Apparent Temperature
            },
          });
        }

        Highcharts.setOptions({
          lang: {
            thousandsSep: ','
          },
          time: {
            useUTC: false,
            //change to your timezone
            timezone: 'Europe/London'
          }
        });

            //Outside Temperature, Dew Point and Humidity
            chart1 = Highcharts.chart('chart1_container', {
              chart: {
                marginLeft: LeftMarginSize,
                marginRight: RightMarginSize,
                zoomType: 'x',
                plotBackgroundColor: '#F9F9F9',
                resetZoomButton: {
                  position: {
                    // align: 'right', // by default
                    // verticalAlign: 'top', // by default
                    x: 100,
                    y: -55
                  }
                },
                events: {
                  load: getChartdata
                },
              },
              title: {
                style: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                text: 'Outside Temperature and Humidity for Today from PYWWS',
              },
              subtitle: {
                text: 'Click and drag in the plot are to zoom'
              },
              xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                max: maxXaxisValue,
                events: {
                  afterSetExtremes: syncExtremes
                }
              },
              yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                lineWidth: 1,
                visible: true,
                labels: {
                  enabled: true,
                  format: '{value}',
                  style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                  }
                },
                softMin: 0,
                softMax: 20,
                tickInterval: 5,
                title: {
                  text: 'Temperature (\xB0C)',
                  style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                  }
                }

              }, { // Secondary yAxis
                lineWidth: 1,
                visible: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                alignTicks: false,
                tickInterval: 20,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                  text: 'Humidity (%)',
                  style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                  },
                },
                labels: {
                  enabled: true,
                  format: '{value}',
                  style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                  }
                },
                opposite: true

              }, { // Third yAxis
                lineWidth: 1,
                visible: true,
                softMin: 0,
                softMax: 20,
                tickInterval: 5,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                  text: 'Dew Point (\xB0C)',
                  style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                  },
                },
                labels: {
                  enabled: true,
                  format: '{value}',
                  style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                  }
                },
                opposite: true
              }],
              tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                borderColor: '#2f7ed8',
                crosshairs: true
              },
              series: [{
                name: 'Outside Temperature',
                type: 'spline',
                color: '#FF0000',
                data: [],
                tooltip: {
                  valueSuffix: '\xB0C'
                }
              }, {
                name: 'Outside Humidity',
                type: 'spline',
                color: '#00FF00',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [],
                tooltip: {
                  valueSuffix: ' %'
                }
              }, {
                name: 'Dew Point',
                type: 'spline',
                color: '#66B2FF',
                yAxis: 2,
                data: [],
                tooltip: {
                  valueSuffix: '\xB0C'
                }
              }, {
                name: 'Apparent Temperature',
                type: 'spline',
                color: '#0000FF',
                data: [],
                tooltip: {
                  valueSuffix: '\xB0C'
                }
              }],
              plotOptions: {
                spline: {      
                  marker: {
                    radius: 0
                  },
                  lineWidth: 1.5,
                  states: {
                    hover: {
                      lineWidth: 2
                    }
                  },
                  threshold: null
                }
              },
              credits: {
                enabled: true
              },
            });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Example JSON data:

```
[
    [1583366478000,5.8,89.0,3.3,4.1,19.1,44.0,3.8,7.6,35,0.0,0.0,993.1,209.0,0,0],
    [1583366778000,5.8,89.0,3.5,4.1,19.1,44.0,3.1,5.4,34,0.0,0.0,993.1,209.0,0,0],
    [1583367092000,5.8,89.0,3.3,4.1,19.1,44.0,3.8,null,27,0.0,0.0,992.8,209.0,0,0],
    [1583367378000,5.8,89.0,3.1,4.1,19.1,44.0,4.5,6.9,22,0.0,0.0,992.6,209.0,0,0],
    [1583367678000,5.8,89.0,3.8,4.1,19.1,44.0,2.2,4.5,19,0.0,0.0,992.9,209.0,0,0],
    [1583367978000,5.8,89.0,4.0,4.1,19.0,44.0,1.6,3.8,21,0.0,0.0,992.9,209.0,0,0],
    [1583368278000,5.8,89.0,3.1,4.1,19.0,44.0,4.5,7.6,20,0.0,0.0,992.7,209.0,0,0],
    [1583368578000,5.8,89.0,4.0,4.1,19.0,44.0,1.6,3.8,21,0.0,0.0,992.6,209.0,0,0],
    [1583368878000,5.8,88.0,3.3,4.0,19.0,44.0,3.8,6.0,27,0.0,0.0,992.7,229.1,0,0],
    [1583369178000,5.8,88.0,3.3,4.0,19.0,44.0,3.8,null,32,0.0,0.0,992.6,229.1,0,0],
    [1583369478000,5.8,88.0,4.3,4.0,19.0,43.0,0.7,2.2,null,0.0,0.0,992.6,229.1,0,0],
    [1583369778000,5.8,88.0,3.8,4.0,18.9,45.0,2.2,6.0,39,0.0,0.0,992.7,229.1,0,0],
    [1583370078000,5.8,88.0,3.1,4.0,18.9,45.0,4.5,8.3,39,0.0,0.0,992.5,229.1,0,0],
    [1583370378000,5.8,88.0,3.3,4.0,18.9,45.0,3.8,5.4,45,0.0,0.0,992.3,229.1,0,0],
    [1583370678000,5.8,88.0,3.5,4.0,18.8,45.0,3.1,6.0,44,0.0,0.0,992.2,229.1,0,0],
    [1583370978000,5.8,88.0,3.8,4.0,18.8,45.0,2.2,3.8,44,0.0,0.0,992.3,229.1,0,0],
    [1583371278000,5.8,88.0,3.8,4.0,18.7,45.0,2.2,3.8,45,0.0,0.0,992.2,229.1,0,0],
    [1583371578000,5.8,88.0,3.5,4.0,18.7,44.0,3.1,4.5,45,0.0,0.0,992.0,229.1,0,0],
    [1583371878000,5.8,88.0,3.5,4.0,18.7,45.0,3.1,5.4,48,0.0,0.0,992.1,229.1,0,0],
    [1583372178000,5.8,88.0,3.8,4.0,18.7,45.0,2.2,3.8,53,0.0,0.0,992.0,229.1,0,0],
    [1583372478000,5.8,88.0,3.8,4.0,18.6,44.0,2.2,3.8,63,0.0,0.0,992.1,229.1,0,0],
    [1583372778000,5.8,88.0,3.3,4.0,18.6,44.0,3.8,5.4,69,0.0,0.0,991.8,229.1,0,0],
    [1583373078000,5.8,88.0,3.5,4.0,18.6,44.0,3.1,null,71,0.0,0.0,991.6,229.1,0,0],
    [1583373378000,5.8,88.0,4.0,4.0,18.6,44.0,1.6,3.8,72,0.0,0.0,991.4,229.1,0,0],
    [1583373678000,5.7,88.0,3.0,3.9,18.5,44.0,4.5,6.0,74,0.0,0.0,991.4,228.9,0,0],
    [1583373978000,5.7,88.0,3.2,3.9,18.5,44.0,3.8,6.9,75,0.0,0.0,991.4,228.9,0,0],
    [1583374278000,5.7,88.0,3.7,3.9,18.5,44.0,2.2,4.5,73,0.0,0.0,991.2,228.9,0,0],
    [1583374578000,5.7,88.0,3.2,3.9,18.5,44.0,3.8,null,71,0.0,0.0,991.1,228.9,0,0],
    [1583374878000,5.7,89.0,3.7,4.0,18.4,44.0,2.2,3.8,70,0.0,0.0,991.1,208.8,0,0],
    [1583375178000,5.7,89.0,3.9,4.0,18.4,44.0,1.6,3.8,64,0.0,0.0,991.2,208.8,0,0],
    [1583375478000,5.7,89.0,2.7,4.0,18.4,44.0,5.4,7.6,62,0.0,0.0,990.7,208.8,0,0],
    [1583375778000,5.7,89.0,3.4,4.0,18.4,44.0,3.1,4.5,62,0.0,0.0,990.6,208.8,0,0],
    [1583376078000,5.7,89.0,2.5,4.0,18.4,44.0,6.0,9.2,64,0.0,0.0,990.6,208.8,0,0],
    [1583376378000,5.7,89.0,3.4,4.0,18.3,44.0,3.1,5.4,64,0.0,0.0,990.4,208.8,0,0],
    [1583376678000,5.7,89.0,3.7,4.0,18.2,44.0,2.2,4.5,64,0.0,0.0,990.5,208.8,0,0],
    [1583376978000,5.7,89.0,3.0,4.0,18.2,44.0,4.5,8.3,66,0.0,0.0,990.3,208.8,0,0],
    [1583377278000,5.7,89.0,3.4,4.0,18.2,44.0,3.1,4.5,67,0.0,0.0,990.1,208.8,0,0],
    [1583377578000,5.7,89.0,3.2,4.0,18.2,44.0,3.8,6.0,62,0.0,0.0,990.1,208.8,0,0],
    [1583377878000,5.6,89.0,3.1,3.9,18.2,44.0,3.8,7.6,59,0.0,0.0,990.1,208.6,0,0],
    [1583378178000,5.6,89.0,3.3,3.9,18.1,44.0,3.1,4.5,56,0.0,0.0,990.0,208.6,0,0],
    [1583378478000,5.6,89.0,3.3,3.9,18.1,44.0,3.1,5.4,53,0.0,0.0,989.9,208.6,0,0],
    [1583378778000,5.6,88.0,3.0,3.8,18.1,44.0,3.8,6.9,49,0.0,0.0,990.0,228.7,0,0],
    [1583379078000,5.6,88.0,3.3,3.8,18.1,44.0,3.1,null,41,0.0,0.0,990.0,228.7,0,0],
    [1583379378000,5.6,88.0,3.7,3.8,18.1,44.0,1.6,3.1,34,0.0,0.0,989.5,228.7,0,0],
    [1583379678000,5.6,88.0,3.3,3.8,18.0,44.0,3.1,4.5,30,0.0,0.0,989.5,228.7,0,0],
    [1583379978000,5.6,88.0,3.7,3.8,18.0,44.0,1.6,5.4,35,0.0,0.0,989.5,228.7,0,0],
    [1583380278000,5.6,88.0,3.3,3.8,18.0,44.0,3.1,8.3,44,0.0,0.0,989.6,228.7,0,0],
    [1583380578000,5.6,88.0,3.5,3.8,18.0,44.0,2.2,6.9,50,0.0,0.0,989.6,228.7,0,0],
    [1583380878000,5.6,88.0,3.5,3.8,18.0,44.0,2.2,4.5,53,0.0,0.0,989.3,228.7,0,0],
    [1583381178000,5.6,88.0,3.0,3.8,17.9,44.0,3.8,6.0,53,0.0,0.0,989.4,228.7,0,0],
    [1583381478000,5.6,88.0,3.3,3.8,17.9,44.0,3.1,null,52,0.0,0.0,989.5,228.7,0,0],
    [1583381778000,5.6,88.0,3.0,3.8,17.9,44.0,3.8,6.0,54,0.0,0.0,989.5,228.7,0,0],
    [1583382078000,5.6,87.0,3.2,3.6,17.9,44.0,3.1,7.6,58,0.0,0.0,989.2,249.0,0,0],
    [1583382378000,5.6,87.0,3.0,3.6,17.9,44.0,3.8,6.0,58,0.0,0.0,988.8,249.0,0,0],
    [1583382678000,5.6,87.0,3.2,3.6,17.8,44.0,3.1,4.5,49,0.0,0.0,989.0,249.0,0,0],
    [1583382978000,5.6,87.0,3.0,3.6,17.8,44.0,3.8,5.4,45,0.0,0.0,988.9,249.0,0,0],
    [1583383278000,5.6,87.0,3.5,3.6,17.8,44.0,2.2,6.0,42,0.0,0.0,988.7,249.0,0,0],
    [1583383578000,5.6,87.0,3.5,3.6,17.8,44.0,2.2,4.5,36,0.0,0.0,988.5,249.0,0,0],
    [1583383878000,5.6,87.0,3.2,3.6,17.8,44.0,3.1,5.4,33,0.0,0.0,988.6,249.0,0,0],
    [1583384178000,5.6,87.0,2.8,3.6,17.7,44.0,4.5,6.9,33,0.0,0.0,988.3,249.0,0,0],
    [1583384478000,5.6,87.0,3.2,3.6,17.8,44.0,3.1,4.5,32,0.0,0.0,988.2,249.0,0,0],
    [1583384778000,5.6,87.0,2.5,3.6,17.8,44.0,5.4,8.3,32,0.0,0.0,988.2,249.0,0,0],
    [1583385078000,5.6,87.0,3.2,3.6,17.8,44.0,3.1,6.9,36,0.0,0.0,988.0,249.0,0,0],
    [1583385378000,5.6,87.0,3.2,3.6,17.7,43.0,3.1,6.9,41,0.0,0.0,987.9,249.0,0,0],
    [1583385678000,5.6,87.0,3.7,3.6,17.7,43.0,1.6,3.1,46,0.0,0.0,988.0,249.0,0,0],
    [1583385978000,5.6,87.0,3.7,3.6,17.7,43.0,1.6,3.8,49,0.0,0.0,988.0,249.0,0,0],
    [1583386278000,5.6,87.0,2.5,3.6,17.7,43.0,5.4,11.4,56,0.0,0.0,987.5,249.0,0,0],
    [1583386578000,5.6,87.0,3.0,3.6,17.6,43.0,3.8,null,56,0.0,0.0,987.4,249.0,0,0],
    [1583386878000,5.6,87.0,3.2,3.6,17.6,44.0,3.1,7.6,55,0.0,0.0,987.7,249.0,0,0],
    [1583387178000,5.6,87.0,3.2,3.6,17.6,44.0,3.1,5.4,55,0.0,0.0,987.7,249.0,0,0],
    [1583387478000,5.7,87.0,3.3,3.7,17.7,44.0,3.1,5.4,55,0.0,0.0,987.6,249.2,0,0],
    [1583387778000,5.7,87.0,2.9,3.7,17.7,44.0,4.5,6.9,54,0.0,0.0,987.5,249.2,0,0],
    [1583388078000,5.7,86.0,2.9,3.5,17.8,45.0,4.5,7.6,49,0.0,0.0,987.2,269.7,0,0],
    [1583388378000,5.7,86.0,3.8,3.5,17.8,45.0,1.6,3.8,46,0.0,0.0,987.2,269.7,0,0],
    [1583388678000,5.7,86.0,3.1,3.5,17.9,45.0,3.8,6.9,45,0.0,0.0,987.1,269.7,0,0],
    [1583388978000,5.7,86.0,3.3,3.5,17.9,45.0,3.1,6.0,44,0.0,0.0,987.1,269.7,0,0],
    [1583389278000,5.7,85.0,3.3,3.4,18.0,46.0,3.1,5.4,44,0.0,0.0,987.0,290.4,0,0],
    [1583389578000,5.7,85.0,2.9,3.4,18.2,47.0,4.5,6.9,45,0.3,0.3,986.8,290.4,0,0],
    [1583389878000,5.7,85.0,2.1,3.4,18.1,47.0,6.9,12.1,45,0.0,0.3,986.7,290.4,0,0],
    [1583390178000,5.7,85.0,3.6,3.4,18.2,47.0,2.2,4.5,48,0.0,0.3,986.7,290.4,0,0],
    [1583390478000,5.7,85.0,2.9,3.4,18.2,47.0,4.5,6.9,50,0.0,0.3,986.8,290.4,0,0],
    [1583390778000,5.7,85.0,3.1,3.4,18.4,48.0,3.8,6.9,55,0.0,0.3,986.4,290.4,0,0],
    [1583391078000,5.7,85.0,3.3,3.4,18.6,50.0,3.1,6.9,59,0.0,0.3,986.3,290.4,24,0],
    [1583391378000,5.7,85.0,2.4,3.4,18.7,50.0,6.0,9.2,64,0.0,0.3,986.3,290.4,88,0],
    [1583391678000,5.7,85.0,2.9,3.4,18.8,51.0,4.5,7.6,68,0.0,0.3,986.1,290.4,176,0],
    [1583391978000,5.7,84.0,2.6,3.2,18.9,50.0,5.4,8.3,72,0.0,0.3,986.0,311.3,341,0],
    [1583392278000,5.7,84.0,2.6,3.2,19.0,50.0,5.4,6.9,76,0.0,0.3,986.2,311.3,634,0],
    [1583392578000,5.7,84.0,3.0,3.2,19.0,50.0,3.8,7.6,78,0.0,0.3,986.3,311.3,634,0],
    [1583392878000,5.7,84.0,2.3,3.2,19.0,46.0,6.0,8.3,82,0.0,0.3,986.1,311.3,856,0],
    [1583393178000,5.7,84.0,3.5,3.2,19.0,46.0,2.2,5.4,81,0.0,0.0,986.0,311.3,883,0],
    [1583393478000,5.7,84.0,3.3,3.2,19.0,46.0,3.1,6.0,77,0.0,0.0,986.0,311.3,925,0],
    [1583393778000,5.8,84.0,3.2,3.3,19.0,46.0,3.8,7.6,72,0.0,0.0,985.9,311.6,1195,0],
    [1583394078000,5.8,84.0,3.9,3.3,19.0,45.0,1.6,3.8,66,0.0,0.0,985.7,311.6,1327,0],
    [1583394378000,5.8,84.0,3.0,3.3,19.0,45.0,4.5,11.4,61,0.0,0.0,985.9,311.6,1396,0],
    [1583394678000,5.8,84.0,3.7,3.3,19.0,45.0,2.2,3.8,60,0.0,0.0,985.5,311.6,1417,0],
    [1583394978000,5.8,84.0,2.2,3.3,19.0,45.0,6.9,12.1,61,0.0,0.0,985.8,311.6,1438,0],
    [1583395278000,5.9,84.0,2.3,3.4,19.0,44.0,6.9,8.3,59,0.0,0.0,985.7,311.8,1322,0],
    [1583395578000,5.9,84.0,2.6,3.4,19.0,44.0,6.0,13.0,62,0.0,0.0,985.9,311.8,1655,0],
    [1583395878000,5.9,84.0,3.5,3.4,19.0,44.0,3.1,5.4,63,0.0,0.0,985.7,311.8,1739,1],
    [1583396178000,5.9,84.0,3.3,3.4,19.0,44.0,3.8,8.3,64,0.0,0.0,985.7,311.8,1787,0],
    [1583396478000,5.9,84.0,3.5,3.4,19.0,44.0,3.1,6.0,68,0.0,0.0,985.5,311.8,1678,1],
    [1583396778000,6.0,83.0,3.4,3.3,18.9,45.0,3.8,6.9,71,0.0,0.0,985.5,333.3,2019,1],
    [1583397078000,6.0,83.0,2.4,3.3,18.9,45.0,6.9,9.2,74,0.0,0.0,985.5,333.3,2089,1],
    [1583397378000,6.0,83.0,3.6,3.3,18.9,44.0,3.1,4.5,73,0.0,0.0,985.3,333.3,2070,1]
]
```

The problem is that the maxXaxisValue variable isn't assigned a value before the chart is loaded so that the maximum value of the axis is not set as 24 hours after the start of the data.

How do I run my populatexAxis_data function to ensure that the maxXaxisValue variable  is set a value before the highcharts are loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working, I needed to set the axis min and max before populating the series with data.

```
function getChartdata() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.npoint.io/4b808e06dc1e356cd1c6',
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      temp_data = data;
      minValue = data[0][0];
      maxValue = minValue + (24 * 3600 * 1000);
      chart1.xAxis[0].update({min: minValue, max: maxValue});

      //Outside Temperature and Humidity
      chart1.series[0].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[1]])); //Outside Temperature
      chart1.series[1].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[2]])); //Outside Humidity
      chart1.series[2].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[4]])); //Dew Point  
      chart1.series[3].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[3]])); //Apparent Temperature
    },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign this min and max to the xAxis by using the `update` feature.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/65z841jo/

```
function getChartdata() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.npoint.io/4b808e06dc1e356cd1c6',
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
      temp_data = data;
      //Outside Temperature and Humidity
      chart1.series[0].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[1]])); //Outside Temperature
      chart1.series[1].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[2]])); //Outside Humidity
      chart1.series[2].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[4]])); //Dew Point  
      chart1.series[3].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[3]])); //Apparent Temperature

      minValue = data[0][0];
      maxValue = minValue + (24 * 3600 * 1000);
      chart1.xAxis[0].update({
        min: minValue,
        max: maxValue
      })
    },
  });
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I can see that your jsfiddle works perfectly however, when I have adapted my code the axis is not updated on loading the page, but is updated after the chart is zoomed and reset bu pressing the button. So I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: In the code which I shared the xAxis is updating while the data is setting, I am not sure how it looks like in your case. Are you able to reproduce it?